# Instead of asymetric encryption, why not use two One-time pad?

Tags: secret-sharing, one-time-pad, three-pass-protocol

Why is the following protocol never used to share a symetric key between two parties ?
⊕ is the XOR operation.

Alice has M and wants to send it to Bob.
Alice generates K₁ randomly.
Bob generates K₂ randomly.

- **Alice** has M.
- **Alice** :   M       -- ·⊕K₁ --> M⊕K₁
- **Alice** sends M⊕K₁ to **Bob**.
- **Bob** : M⊕K₁    -- ·⊕K₂ --> M⊕K₁⊕K₂
- **Bob** sends M⊕K₁⊕K₂ to **Alice**.
- **Alice** :   M⊕K₁⊕K₂ -- ·⊕K₁ --> M⊕K₂
- **Alice** sends M⊕K₂ to **Bob**.
- **Bob**:  M⊕K₂    -- ·⊕K₂ --> M
- **Bob** has M.

Of course, K₁ and K₂ need to be the same size as M.

Comment: This is the [Three-pass_protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-pass_protocol). It's not secure when using xor, but secure for certain other operations.

Comment: If you look through the [tag:three-pass-protocol]-tag you'll find a couple of duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's why it doesn't work:

Suppose someone in the middle hears $M \oplus K_1$, $M \oplus K_1 \oplus K_2$ and $M \oplus K_2$.

Then, what they could do is xor the three of them together, giving:

$$(M \oplus K_1) \oplus (M \oplus K_1 \oplus K_2) \oplus (M \oplus K_2) = M$$

Thus recovering the message.

Comment: Thank you, I am really brain dead :|